# How can i move between items in listBox and show the item name on a label.Text?

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a listBox1 with 4 items inside. I can use the keys to move up-down between the items or click with the mouse once on each item in both cases the selected items will be highlight with blue marked .

I want when I click on an item or when I move the keys up and down over the items it will change the label.Text with the current item name.

For example in on the item moses so label1.Text will contain moses.
Moved to the next item with arrow key up so now label1.Text contain daniel.
Clicked with the mouse on the item number 3 now label1.Text will contain dana.

Tried with this:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                //listBox1.Items.Add(fsi[i].Name + Environment.NewLine);
                label2.Text = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
            }
        }
```

But its not worrking.

Comment: `winform` or `webapp`..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   listBox1.Items.Add("Item1");
   listBox1.Items.Add("Item2");
   listBox1.Items.Add("Item3");
   listBox1.Items.Add("Item4");
 }

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   label1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really expected your code to work? Why iterate over the whole collection, if you just need to check for the currently selected item?

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem lbi = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as ListBoxItem);
    label2.Text = lbi.Content.ToString();
}
```

or if you're using webforms:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `List<CustomClass>/ObservableCollection<CustomClass>` as `ItemSource` for `ListBox` try the following way in listbaox selected index changed event

```
var listTapped = sender as ListBox;

var selectedUser = listTapped.SelectedItem as CustomClass;
if (selectedUser == null)
    return;
label2.Text = selectedUser.Name; //
```

Answer (score 0):

ListBox contains event `SelectedIndexChanged`. It raises on such conditions. I think you should use it. Then you should use SelectedValue property to get correct string.

Comment: Ehm, he's already using the event. Have you even checked his code before posting an answer?

Comment: @walther thank you for paying attention into this. Edited my answer